# AppWidget click lost after system restarts my process

Tags: android, click, widget, android-appwidget

i am making an appwidget and i have problems with click event, which is lost when system kills the widget's process and later restarts it. this also happens after screen rotate.

building against SDK version 7 and running on emulator (2.1) and a real device with 2.3.3.

my onUpdate method:

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    for (int wid : appWidgetIds) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onUpdate widget #" + wid);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyClass.class);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, wid);

        PendingIntent clickIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        RemoteViews widget = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
        widget.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_layout, clickIntent);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(wid, widget);
    }

    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
}
```

where R.id.widget_layout is id of linear layout of the appwidget. i tried to add this click event also to a textview, but with same result.

i am fighting this problem for several days and i found some people with this same problem, but no solution works for me :( i also tried different pending intent flags without any success.

second problem is, when i add another appwidget on home screen, it does not react to click events. in logcat i see the message from onUpdate method "onUpdate widget #xy", but the appwidget does not react to clicks. only the first appwidget placed on home screen reacts to clicks, but only for some time. any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say the first widget stops responding to clicks, do you mean that the `onUpdate` method is not being called?  Perhaps put some code in [`onEnabled(Context context)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html#onEnabled%28android.content.Context%29) to see if that's being called instead, and if so, put whatever logic is necessary in that function.  Also, you can catch intents via the `onReceive` method (found at the same link) to see which ones your widget is actually receiving.

Also, ensure that the `Context` that you have the receiver running in (the one that gets passed to this function) is an Application or Service, and not an Activity, or the reference to it may not persist.

You must also make sure that every time you update the widget with a `RemoteViews` object, you send all of the data needed to fully reconstruct the widget.  This is because on, e.g., screen rotation, the system doesn't have anything to reconstruct the widget with beside the very latest `RemoteViews` you passed it.

Comment: the click stops working = MyClass activity is not shown after clicking the widget. i update my widget only from a service. so the onUpdate is only called when i place a widget on a home screen. onEnabled is called, when it should, when the first appwidget is placed. how can i ensure that the Context is not an activity? when i redraw the widget with RemoteViews, should i also attach the click event?

Comment: your last paragraph is the answer. my problem was, that i redraw my widget from a service and i did not know, that i should also re-attach the click events. now, after i redraw the widget, i re-attach the click events and everything works fine. my widget survives restart of its process and also a screen rotation. thank you!